# Can i use LINQ in ADO .Net?

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net

This is a insert to my simple employee database, which is in SSMS:

```
Insert into dbo.tbl_empdetail (empid,empname,salary) values(@emp,@emp_name,@emp_salary)
```

and this is a update:

```
string query = "Update dbo.tbl_empdetail set empname=@name,salary=@salary where empid=@id"
```

How can i do it with LINQ?

Like this:

```
from student in studentList
                where student.age>10          
                select student.Name;
```

Comment: I know two ways. You can use an ORM, like EF. Or you can write down your own ORM, using reflection of exact mapper. The second way is more flexible, however the first one much easier and is commonly used.

Comment: I gotta admit, I don't really understand: you posted an insert query, an update query and then a LINQ select.. The former two and the latter aren't really anything to do with each other; queries != modifications (reads != writes)

Comment: I know they aren't the same. The Linq query is just an example.

Comment: The question as written is not possible. Linq stands for Language Integrated Query, and thus can not be used for data modification (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/). However, with for example Entity Framework, you can use Linq to get the objects, modify them and update/insert/delete with EF.

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer to your question would be to look at implementing `IQueryable` interface. check out  https://github.com/mattwar/iqtoolkit

If all you wish is to use a typed query to work with a database, the best way would be to use an ORM like "Entity Framework" or "NHibernate". They generally have a LINQ provider that will allow you to query a database.